# Android activity image background size

Tags: android, image, background, size, screen

I am a bit confused on creating an image which will be acting as a background for my activities. So, in short, my aim is that my application should be able to fit the different screen sizes. Therefore, what size in pixel should my three images be to be able to fill the screen of the device in ldpi, mdpi and hdpi?

Thank you for any response.

Comment: please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 67):

In `ldpi`-folder, the recommended size is 240x320.

In `mdpi`-folder, the recommended size is 320x480.

In `hdpi`-folder, the recommended size is 480x800.

More information about this subject can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Answer (score 50):

ldpi   240x320.

mdpi   320x480.

hdpi   480x800.

xhdpi 640*960.

xxhdpi 960x1440.

---

**updated Jan,09,2016**

```
                            ldpi     mdpi     hdpi     xhdpi    xxhdpi     xxxhdpi
Launcher And Home           36*36    48*48   72*72    96*96    144*144    192*192
Action Bar And Tab          24*24    32*32   48*48    64*64    96*96      128*128
Notification                18*18    24*24   36*36    48*48    72*72      96*96
Background                  240*320  320*480 480*800 768*1280 1080 *1920  1440*2560
```

---

**updated Sep,23,2016**

@CDrosos thanks.

This is helpful also: Device Metrics - [design.google.com/devices](http://design.google.com/devices)

Comment: what about for xxxhdpi?

Comment: when I used this sizes , the image dont match parent ?  did you know the reason

Comment: please give me more details . these sizes are common.

Comment: The ratio between xxxhdpi and mdpi is 4x for launcher / home / notification, but it is 4.5x for background. Can you explain why?

Comment: This is helpful also: Device Metrics - https://design.google.com/devices/

Comment: @S.M_Emamian what about tablets (something like 1024x600 px - 160 dpi) ? I think 320x480 image is not suitable in this case, any advice?

Answer (score 4):

04 / 2013 : 
I have read another specifications in android developers

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html