# Android ViewPager + GridView with images taking too much HEAP Memory

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to make a Level selector to my game, now it's working but, it's really slow on some phones and some times not working (FC), I realized that it's using too much heap memory.

I'm quite new on android dev, so here's my code, I hope you can help me.

**ACTIVITY WITH THE VIEWPAGER:**

```
   setContentView(R.layout.level_selector);
   ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
   ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mypagerwontwork); //cool id huh
   myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

**VIEW PAGER ADAPTER:**

```
  public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    activity.getSystemService(activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     if(position == 0)
     {
         View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.world1, null);
         final GridView gridview = (GridView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gridLvl);
         gridview.setAdapter(new LevelAdapter(activity,"World1"));
         gridview.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
         ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout); 
         return layout;
     }
```

**GRID VIEW ADAPTER:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        if (mWorld.equals("World1"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(World1[position]);
        }
```

**USEFUL INFORMATION:**

- There are 3 "Worlds" (View page) each with a different background
- Each "World" has 15 Images, with number from 1 to 15.
- The image size is: +- 12kb
- The BG size is: +- 140kb

I hope it's clear.

thanks.

Comment: Did you calculate to see how much memory those images will take?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that my images were too big, not the size, but the resolution.

I had to resize them to ldpi, mdpi and hdpi.

these sizes can be found at:

[Android activity image background size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694830/android-activity-image-background-size)

[Button Image size in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697440/button-image-size-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid creating objects in getView methods (like in your grid view adapter). Instead you can use ViewHolder pattern:

http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166